# Validation of integers on solidity

Tags: solidity, solidity-0.5.x, integers

I have this function and require the _price variable to be positive, But when I pass a negative int, it accepts the integer! How can I validate the input?

The Contract :

```
function createProduct(string memory _name, uint _price) public {
    require(bytes(_name).length > 0);
    require(_price > 0);
    //..... emit the product name & price
}
```

Test JS with moka & chai :

```
let createProductResult;
//before
createProductResult = await marketplace.createProduct('test', -1);

//it ...
const creationEvent = createProductResult.logs[0].args;
console.log(creationEvent.price.toString());
```

Not only the request is not rejected but also the console gives me `115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007913129639935`
for the price I just sent!

Comment: The number you mentioned is the max value for a `uint256`, this is more likely an issue with the ABI encoder you're using. `uint`s are unsigned, so they cannot be negative. This makes your `require` for `price > 0` redundant.

Comment: yeah I'm awair of that , just was checking the price not to be 0 , and came across this by chance !

Comment: This may or may not be an issue with the ABI encoder frontend in the library you are using. Either they are not validating the sign of parameters that are supposed to be unsigned or they just do wrapping arithmetic on them. EVM doesn't have native types, negative numbers are just two's complement representation. In any case, you should file a bug with the library that you are using.